# Firefox addon: How do I pass a variable from my sidebar to a new tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've created a sidebar that displays a list of values. When the user double clicks on one of those values, a new tab opens and is supposed to display detailed information about the value selected in the sidebar. I need to pass a javascript object (or some other type of value) over to my new tab which has a script attached to the xul file which will load data from a remote web service. How do I get this done (passing the variable to my new tab)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/working_with_windows_in_chrome_code